# how to add new value to a immutable map of a immutable list?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

Below is my code

```
 // messageList is a Immutable List
 const newMessage: any = messageList.map((msg: any) => {
            msg.set('name', 'bbb');
        });
```

but I got

```
msg.set is not a function
```

in console.

Something is wrong?

Comment: can you provide the result of `messageList.toJS()`

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to follow this steps:

From docs: Add new key/value pair to a Map with set()

```
const updatedMap = oldMap.set(key, value)
```

Example

```
const avengersMap = Immutable.Map({
  ironMan: 'Tony Stark',
  captainAmerica: 'Steve Rogers'
});

const moreAvengers = avengersMap.set('blackWidow', 'Natasha Romanov');
```

The same goes for typescript.

[(Example ref)](http://untangled.io/immutable-js-get-set-update-and-delete-data-from-maps/)

Some notes:  as you are probably aware you cannot modify an immutable list, so .map over it won't give you the possibility of update the element in the list. You have to create a new list with that element modified.

Example of updating in a list (from an react reducer):

```
function fn(state) { 
     targets = state.get('targets');
     targets = targets.push(action.data);
     return state
          .set('targets', targets)
}
```